# Docker does not pick up host DNS configuration after upgrade

Tags: docker, dns, ubuntu-18.04

After upgrading Docker to *Docker version 18.09.2, build 6247962* on Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS, the DNS configuration inside a container always points to Google's DNS servers only. Previously, the `/etc/resolv.conf` file inside a container would contain the host's DNS configuration.

File `/etc/resolv.conf` now looks like this:

```
$ sudo docker run -it centos:6 bash
[root@459f5102cc74 /]# cat /etc/resolv.conf  
# This file is managed by man:systemd-resolved(8). Do not edit.
#
# This is a dynamic resolv.conf file for connecting local clients directly to
# all known uplink DNS servers. This file lists all configured search domains.
#
# Third party programs must not access this file directly, but only through the
# symlink at /etc/resolv.conf. To manage man:resolv.conf(5) in a different way,
# replace this symlink by a static file or a different symlink.
#
# See man:systemd-resolved.service(8) for details about the supported modes of
# operation for /etc/resolv.conf.

# No DNS servers known.

nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
[root@459f5102cc74 /]#
```

The only fix I found so far is to manually configure DNS in `/etc/docker/daemon.json`:

```
$ cat /etc/docker/daemon.json 
{
  "dns": ["10.0.0.1"],
  "dns-search": ["example.org"]
}
```

After restarting the Docker daemon I see:

```
$ sudo docker run -it centos:6 bash
[root@d1049c2c3d96 /]# cat /etc/resolv.conf 
search example.org
nameserver 10.0.0.1
```

Is there a way to make Docker pick up the host's DNS configuration automatically?

(P.S. The host is configured statically – i.e., it is not using DHCP.)